# BeautifulSoup 4: Extracting multiple titles and links from different ptag(s)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, scrapy

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/123456">title_1</a> 
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/789000">title_2</a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

My Code:

```
def web(WebUrl):
    site = urlparse(WebUrl)
    code = requests.get(WebUrl)
    plain = code.text
    s = BeautifulSoup(plain, "html.parser")
    p_containers = s.find('p', {'class':'title'})

    for title in s.find_all('p', {'class':'title'}):
        line = title.get_text()
        print(line)
        for link in p_containers.find_all('a'):
            line2 = link.get('href')
            print(site.netloc + str(line2))
```

Hi guys, I need some help with this, my task is to extract titles and links from a webpage, I was able to extract the titles but not the links. When I try to scrape the links, I got only the first link successfully scraped, the following links got ignored and replaced with the first scraped link.

Comment: Without checking I think the answer might be to change `p_containers = s.find('p', {'class':'title'})` to `p_containers = s.find_all('p', {'class':'title'})`

Comment: No I was wrong, answer to follow!

Comment: Opps, there's a missing indentation on the for loop, it's nested

Comment: If my answer was helpful can you mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the bits in your code, but are just a little bit off. I think the most simple way to get the titles and links is by using the below.

```
site = """<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/123456">title_1</a> 
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/789000">title_2</a> 
    </p>
</div>"""

s = BeautifulSoup(site, "html.parser")

for title in s.find_all('p', {'class':'title'}):
    links = [x['href'] for x in title.find_all('a', href=True)]
    line = title.get_text()
    print(line)
    print(links)
```

You can see that the links object is a list, that's just in case there's a situation where there's multiple links for each title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will help to find_all values from it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/123456">title_1</a> 
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="title">
       <a href="/news/789000">title_2</a> 
    </p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'title'}):
    link = None
    if i.find('a'):
        link = i.find('a').get('href')
    print('Title:', i.get_text(strip=True), 'Link:', link)
# Output as:
# Title: title_1 Link: /news/123456
# Title: title_2 Link: /news/789000
```